# Cannot pass in FlxTypedGroup class param using FlxG.overlap

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I want the player to pickup objects in my game using the code below, but I am getting:

> Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flixel::FlxSprite@51e1b69 to Player.

```
    ...
    FlxG.overlap(weapons, players, onPickup)
}

private function onPickup(wep:Weapon, player:Player):Void
{ 
    //access player function 
}
```

I've initialized the players and weapons already as below, and added to the group

```
players= new FlxTypedGroup<Player>();
weapons= new FlxTypedGroup<Weapon>();
```

`Weapon` extends `FlxSprite` and `Player` extends `FlxTypedGroup<FlxSprite>`.

I'm using `FlxTypedGroup` because I want the player to have multiple sprites associated with it.

Please help so I can access the player class variables!

If I replace `player:Player` with `player:FlxSprite` there is no error, but then I can no longer access `Player` class functions.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is probably a little bit late, but there are a few things you can try:

You could try using [`FlxSpriteGroup`](http://api.haxeflixel.com/flixel/group/FlxSpriteGroup.html) for `Player` instead of `FlxTypedGroup`. It may take some work to get it working the way you want.

Also, the reason why it's giving you an error, is because `overlap` and `collide` will (by default) drill down through your Groups until it comes to an actual object...

How to explain... If you have a `FlxTypedGroup<Player>` and your `Player` object extends `FlxTypedGroup<PlayerPart>` (if `PlayerPart` extends `FlxSprite` or something), when you do `FlxG.overlap(weapons, players, onPickup)`, overlap is NOT going to pass the `Player` object, it's going to pass the `PlayerPart` object that overlapped - in fact, it's going to call `onPickup` once for EVERY `PlayerPart` object that overlaps a weapon - possibly the same one - this `update`.

You can use this behavior to your advantage, if you can figure it out - make your Player group contain several PlayerParts but set all of them to `allowCollisions  = NONE` except for one which will be your hitbox, etc.

There's lots of things you can do, it's just figuring out the specifics. Good Luck!

Comment: You are right on the FlxTypedGroup Resolution of members. But the OP tries to group his players into 'p;ayers'. Can you make a group of FlxSpriteGroups, and run an overlap on the parent group, like the OP tried to ?

Comment: And still, a FlxSpriteGroup will only work for simple transitions. If you upscale or rotate the group, the members positions and hitboxes will mess up. There are know issues on that: https://github.com/HaxeFlixel/flixel/issues/975

Comment: If his `Player` Object extends `FlxTypedGroup` - like he says it does, you would NOT be able to use `overlap` or `collide` they way he has it now. 

There are a lot of ways to 'solve' the problem.
Using `FlxSpriteGroup` might be the simplest solution for him, if he's not worried about complex transitions - it might not work, depending on the situation.

Comment: Yes, you're right on that. FlxTypedGroup will not add itself into the quadtree. Only it's members. My question is : But even if he made Player extend FlxSpriteGroup, would he be able to add his Players into another group (players) and pass the `players` to `Flx.overlap` ?

Comment: I'm asking because I think that his logic (making a group that contains groups), is wrong in the first place. My impression is that you can pass either a Group of Sprites to Flx.overlap, or a single Group. Not a group that contains Groups. I hope I've made myself more clear now. btw can you please edit your post so I can upvote it?

Comment: You can **absolutely** pass groups of groups to `FlxG.overlap` - you just have to understand what you would be getting back in the overlap callback.